# Mac OS X Mojave - set environment variable permanently

Tags: macos, environment-variables, macos-mojave

I am using mac os mojave (10.14.3). I set the environment variable in both
**`~/.bash_profile`** and **`~/.bashrc`** and I ran both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`. Then in the same terminal I can see the values which I set (using `printenv`), but if I open a new terminal then I can not see previously set env variable.

Please give some suggestions.

### Update

In mac os Bigsur(11.2.3), the default terminal was zsh ( I did not check for other versions) and setting envs in `~/.zshenv` as in

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0/' >> ~/.zshenv
```

and running `. ~/.zshenv` helped me saving the envs permanently

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/289060/setting-variables-in-environment-plist

Comment: Please follow steps [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks). Hope it helps

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656031/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-macos-mojave?answertab=active#answer-56668060), using launchctl on macOS Mojave 10.14, worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

This works for OS X 10.14 "Mojave":

Step 1: go to your `$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents` directory and create `setenv.MY_VAR.plist` file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>setenv.MY_VAR</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
    <string>setenv</string>
    <string>MY_VAR</string>
    <string>SOME_VALUE_FOR_MY_VAR</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Pay attantion that your file name and entries in the file match.

STEP 2: Run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/setenv.MY_VAR.plist` or - restart the system.

STEP 3: Restart your Terminal app.

STEP 4: Check if the var is there: `env`. It should give you: `MY_VAR=SOME_VALUE_FOR_MY_VAR`.

If you want to do more changes, first do `launchctl unload...` than `launchctl load...` again.

This is per user setting. If you want to set for all users, try doing the same in `/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Comment: If you want to do it for all users I think the correct place is `/Library/LaunchAgents`, not `/Library/LaunchDaemons`

Comment: @JosephFitzgerald That's what the last sentence says. :-)

Comment: Not quite.  You wrote Daemons when the correct place is agents.  The last sentence is supposed to highlight your own Libraries folder vs the root Libraries folder.

Comment: The last sentence has been edited as of October 2021 and should now be correct. Thanks, @JosephFitzgerald, for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you're setting the environment variables, but make sure that you're using the export command to persist it across shells, e.g. `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim`. You can then check what variables were exported from another shell with `export -p`.

Running `bash` directly from the command line will source your .bashrc file. If the .bashrc file isn't being sourced when you open a new terminal window, it's possible that you're [not running bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94490/bash-doesnt-read-bashrc-unless-manually-started).

In the case where `/bin/sh` is by default your default shell (as opposed to bash), you can change that by running `chsh -s $(which bash)`.