# Can't install rJava in R/RStudio

Tags: java, r, macos, rjava

I'm trying to install 'rJava' package on my RStudio. But it gives me this error:

```
configure: error: one or more Java tools are missing.

*** JDK is incomplete! Please make sure you have a complete JDK. JRE is *not* sufficient.
configure: error: ./configure failed for jri
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Users/art/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava’
* restoring previous ‘/Users/art/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

When I try to install on R, it gives me:

```
checking whether JNI programs run... configure: error: Unable to run a simple JNI program. Make sure you have configured R with Java support (see R documentation) and check config.log for failure reason.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Users/art/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava’
* restoring previous ‘/Users/art/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava’
```

An old solution : `sudo R CMD javareconf` used to work for me but not any more.

This is what it gives:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_252
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
Non-system Java on macOS

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include/darwin  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

`java -version` gives:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.46.0.20-SA-macosx) (build 1.8.0_252-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.46.0.20-SA-macosx) (build 25.252-b14, mixed mode)
```

My system is MacOS Mojave 10.14.6, could anyone please help me with this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to JRE folder. You need to set it to JDK folder.
You can use `/usr/libexec/java_home -v <version you want>` to get the path you need for `JAVA_HOME`. For instance, to get the path to the 1.7 JDK you can run `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` and it will return the path to the JDK. In your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` just add `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home -v <version>` and you should be good.
Do `javac -version` if you want to check JDK installation.

Comment: `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` gives me `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home`. I opened `.bash_profile` and added `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` but it didn't work. I also tried changing it to `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home`. It didn't work either. `javac -version` returns `Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/javac" (-1)`

Comment: I changed it to `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home` and `javac -version` gives `javac 1.8.0_252`. Unfortunately, I tried to install `rJava` in both R and RStudio. They gave the same error as op.

Comment: Download JAVA 8 from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) and then set the path for JAVA_HOME in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Umm, I didnt find a way to set path in `.bashrc`

Comment: Did you download the Oracle JDK 8? Setting path in `.bashrc` file is simply pasting the `export JAVA_HOME=<path to oracle jdk 8 directory>` in the file

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55648312/mac-os-x-mojave-set-environment-variable-permanently) out for setting environment variables on your system.